# Negation of statement and equal sign?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am trying to negate the following statement:

$$(∀,∈) ( +  = )$$

I turned this into:

$$∃ ∈ S ¬(x, y)  (x - y ≠ xy)$$

Is this correct? What is the right way to negate the plus and equal sign?

Comment: Maybe $(∃ x∈ S, ∃ y∈ S) (x +y ≠ xy)$?

Comment: @RobertZ  For the first version in the question, and before your edit, I was just seeing parentheses and operators, with blanks for $x, y$ and $S$. No idea why.

Comment: $\in$ needs the names of objects (sets, variables, etc.) on either side of it. $\exists \in S$ is meaningless. Also, $\lnot$ should have a full statement after it, not just a pair of variables.

Comment: You don't generally change $+$ to $-$ in order to negate something logically. The statement $2 + 2 = 2\cdot 2$ is true, and so is $2 - 2 \neq 2\cdot 2$ -- those are the right-hand parts of your two formulas with $x = 2$ and $y = 2.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following

$$(\exists x,y\in S)(x+y\ne xy)$$

What does it mean for the above sentence to be false? Do you see the corrections you need to make?

EDIT:

Back to the original question. The negation of $$(\forall x,y\in S)(x+y= xy)$$
is indeed the following
$$\neg(\forall x,y\in S)(x+y= xy)\tag{1}$$
but you can "simplify" (that's a matter of perspective) by moving the negation past the quantifier $\forall$ to get
$$(\exists x,y\in S)\neg(x+y= xy).\tag{2}$$
Last step is to negate an equality statement. Thus we obtain
$$(\exists x,y\in S)(x+y\ne xy).\tag{3}$$

I want to emphasize $(1\text{-}3)$ are all correct.

Comment: Do I need to say ¬(∃x,y∈S) (x+y≠xy) ?

Comment: What you wrote is indeed the negation. What I wanted to point out in a subtle way was that, in general, $\neg(\exists x,y\in S)[\varphi(x,y)]\iff (\forall x,y\in S)[\neg\varphi(x,y)]$. That is to say, negations can commute with $\forall$ and $\exists$ but changes one to the other.

Comment: Ahaa, I see thank you! 
Does that also mean that ∀∃,(,)+(,) ⟺ ∃∀, ¬(,)+ ¬(,) (because the quantifiers changes) ?

Comment: If you are negating $(\forall x)(\exists y)(Q(x,y)\text{ or }P(x,y))$, then you should start with $\neg(\forall x)(\exists y)(Q(x,y)\text{ or }P(x,y))$ and (step by step) bring the negation inside. Be aware, $\neg(\varphi\text{ or }\psi)\iff (\neg\varphi)\text{ and }(\neg\psi)$.